# Queue async function and limit to 1 parallel execution

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an async javascript function, lets call it `generateThumbnail`. The function gets called on a specific event. (e.g. a button click). The problem is, that doing the task multiple times in parallel will make the script run out of memory. So I want to execute it sequentially.

```js
function generateThumbnail(arg) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('start', arg);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('end', arg);
      resolve(arg);
    }, 1000);
  });
}


// I tried the following, which is not working,
// as it still results in multiple pending promises at a given time.
var lastExecution;
async function generateThumbnailQueued(arg) {
  //await last execution... only start after its done
  await lastExecution;

  lastExecution = generateThumbnail(arg);
  return lastExecution;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="generateThumbnailQueued(++this.i || (this.i = 1))">Do Task</button>
```

Pressing the button 3 times fast results in the output

```
start 1
end 1
start 2
start 3
end 2
end 3
```

What I want is

```
start 1
end 1
start 2
end 2
start 3
end 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the promise from the last execution handy, and chain each new invocation to that...

```
let promise = Promise.resolve();

function userPressesButton() {
    let arg = // ...
    promise = promise.then(() => generateThumbnail(arg));
    return promise;
}
```

Comment: @RolandStarke, it will consume memory, but not a leak.  When you know you're not executing a promise, clean up with `promise = Promise.resolve();`